# Run node.js server locally

Tags: node.js, npm, server, command-prompt

I'm trying to run my node.js server locally. Before, I had done it in Replit, where it makes it easy to set up. I'm a little stuck though.

I have a folder for my project, with a server.js file, package.json, package-lock.json, and a public folder containing index.html. I'm using socket.io, express, http, and cookie-parser. They are all in a node_modules folder.

In server.js, I use
`const { Server } = require('socket.io');`
This worked in Replit.

The package.json file contains these dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.1",
    "cookie": "^0.4.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "socket.io": "^4.4.1"
  }
```

I use the command
`.load correct\path\to\server.js`
in the Node.js command line.

When I run server.js in Node.js, I get this message:
Cannot find module 'socket.io'

Help?

Comment: You should run `node server.js` from `correct/path/to`, not use a "Node.js command line".

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to install the dependencies, try executing npm install, after that you use "node" to run your code.

For example: `node correct\path\to\server.js`

Answer (score 0):

You need to install all the dependent modules through npm install, In your case, you need to install

```
node-SQL server
```

```
npm install node-sqlserver
```

Generally your source code will be having a

```
package.json
```

. This file specifies all the dependent modules required to run the application, but here this file is missing.